# Is it possible to split an npm package into smaller interchangable submodules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I was wondering if it is possible to split up my package (call it "shapes") into smaller "sub-packages" or submodules.

My main package can be installed by saying `npm install shapes` and my sub-packages should be available via `npm install shapes/square` etc.

The subpackage should include the necessary framework from the shapes package and the "square specific" code but it shouldn't load the content of other, unwanted sub-packages.

Comment: Kind of, scope packages are kind of like that.  eg.. `@myscope/shapes`  and `@myscope/square` etc.   If you don't mind them all be in 1 package, you can also do `mypackage` only, and just use sub-dirs, main issue here though is that if you only wanted `circle` you would also be installing `square`,  I tend to keep my packages very small, and use my own private npm repository using a scope..

Comment: Oh, isn't there a more elegant way? I already found those scoped packages like the `@types/xy` but I thought there would be something like a best practice.

Comment: No, there is no best practise here..  eg. `lodash` does things like `lodash.clonedeep` / `lodash.isequal` etc, for it's module based version.   So you could maybe use that technique.